# Installing gcc 2.95 from source on Fedora 32

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation

Am trying to install gcc 2.95 (gcc-2.95.1.tar.gz) downloaded from here (https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/) on Fedora 32.

Ideally, I don't want to "pollute" my distro's normal gcc - but if I can install using `yum/dnf`, that's fine also. I'm OK with compiling from source.

I started by issuing the command:

```
tar -zxvf gcc-2.95.1.tar.gz
```

obtained the directory gcc-2.95.1 then

```
mkdir inst
cd inst
... copied path to inst
cd ../gcc-2.95.1
```

so far, so good, but then I run:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/pol/Downloads/sw/lang/gcc/inst
```

and receive the error message:

```
[pol@UNKNOWN gcc-2.95.1]$ ./configure --prefix=/home/pol/Downloads/sw/lang/gcc/inst
Configuring for a x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu host.
Invalid configuration `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu': machine `x86_64-unknown' not recognized
Invalid configuration `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu': machine `x86_64-unknown' not recognized
Unrecognized host system name x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.
[pol@UNKNOWN gcc-2.95.1]$
```

I ran:

```
env | grep -i unknown
printenv | grep -i unknown
```

Neither of which returned anything.

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to pass in a machine type or something like that?

I ran

```
./configure --help
```

and there was a HOST option, but on my machine, this is blank, so I put in $HOSTNAME

```
[pol@UNKNOWN gcc-2.95.1]$ echo $HOSTNAME
localhost.localdomain
```

which allowed the configure to run, but then when I ran:

```
make
```

the result (failed) was:

```
gcc  -DIN_GCC     -g -O2  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H    -I. -I. -I./config -I./../include \
  -DGCC_INCLUDE_DIR=\"/home/pol/Downloads/sw/lang/gcc/inst/lib/gcc-lib/localhost.localdomain/2.95.1/include\" \
  -DGPLUSPLUS_INCLUDE_DIR=\"/home/pol/Downloads/sw/lang/gcc/inst/lib/gcc-lib/localhost.localdomain/2.95.1/../../../..`echo /home/pol/Downloads/sw/lang/gcc/inst | sed -e 's|^/home/pol/Downloads/sw/lang/gcc/inst||' -e 's|/[^/]*|/..|g'`/include/g++-3\" \
  -DLOCAL_INCLUDE_DIR=\"/home/pol/Downloads/sw/lang/gcc/inst/include\" \
  -DCROSS_INCLUDE_DIR=\"/home/pol/Downloads/sw/lang/gcc/inst/lib/gcc-lib/localhost.localdomain/2.95.1/../../../../localhost.localdomain/sys-include\" \
  -DTOOL_INCLUDE_DIR=\"/home/pol/Downloads/sw/lang/gcc/inst/lib/gcc-lib/localhost.localdomain/2.95.1/../../../../localhost.localdomain/include\" \
  -c `echo ./cccp.c | sed 's,^\./,,'`
In file included from cccp.c:21:
config.h:8:10: fatal error: localhost.localdomain/xm-localhost.localdomain.h: No such file or directory
    8 | #include "localhost.localdomain/xm-localhost.localdomain.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:3339: cccp.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pol/Downloads/sw/lang/gcc/gcc-2.95.1/gcc'
make: *** [Makefile:1466: all-gcc] Error 2
[pol@UNKNOWN gcc-2.95.1]$
```

If there's a repo that has it, I'm all ears! I ran:

```
yum list all | grep gcc | grep 95
```

and nothing was returned!

Please bear in mind that I am **not** a `C` or a `*nix` expert, so please give simple baby-steps. Let me know if anything else is required in terms of further input!

Comment: gcc 2.95 is 20 years old and predates the x86-64 architecture. You might have more luck with a 32 bit i386 build, but... *why*? Trying to use it makes as much sense as wanting to use Borland Turbo C++.

Comment: @Shawn - I have a problem with legacy code which has a -fwritable-strings option - from [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.0/changes.html)  we have: `GCC no longer accepts the -fwritable-strings option. Use named character arrays when you need a writable string.` - so I was trying to install an older version. I remembered 2.95 from waaay back. Are there any 3 versions that would make sense for me? I'm all ears - and thanks for your input!

Comment: @Shawn - am now trying to run 3.46... will post back! Am in make - so far so good. Going out with missus - later...

Comment: I'd work on fixing the broken code instead of messing with ancient long obsolete compiler releases.